# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un código al mover un objeto en Blender por medio de python bpy?

Tags: python

Lo que busco un es que se detecte cuando el objeto se traslada de posición y a partir de ahí me ejecute una acción.

Un ejemplo de lo que busco:

```
bpy.data.objects["miObjeto"].location.onChange(myFunction)

def myFunction():
    #do stuff every time location is changed...
```

Comment: No sé cómo se podrá resolver exactamente. Aquí en el sitio de blender.stackexchange.com hay una [guía para lo que buscas](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/953), pero está en inglés.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo en ese sitio está la solución, me funcionó :)