# Como puedo saber la posición local de un objeto en Blender bpy?

Tags: python, blender

La idea es imprimir la posición local del objeto.

Comment: Hola Sim. Por favor considera redactar mejor tus preguntas. No coincido con los votantes de que la pregunta sea demasiado amplia, pero no luce como una pregunta de calidad para el sitio. Te recomiendo revisar la edición que hice a [tu primera pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/34497/227) y que revises [ask]. Espero que la puedas editar conforme a ello y pueda ser re abierta.

Answer (score 3):

Si te refieres a la locación seria:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['nombre_del_objeto']
print(obj.location)
```

mas simple>

```
print(bpy.data.objects['nombre_del_objeto'].location)
```

mi versión de blender es 2.69

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguien que me explique por qué le han puesto voto negativo

Comment: lo mismo me pregunte @fredyfx

Comment: Yo también. No manejo Blender por lo que en un principio pensé 'pues habrá un error', así que busco documentación y resulta que es correcta y las dos capturas que añadiste después en tu edición lo aclaran bastante :). Yo suelo dejar un comentario si voto negativo o por el cierre para dar la oportunidad de rectificar al usuario, pero en el tema de los votos siempre hay un componente subjetivo que depende de las preferencias de cada uno. La pregunta posiblemente  pueda ser cerrada por su baja calidad pero eso no implica que se deba votar en contra de una respuesta que es correcta.